# Can't access Azure services through Curity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, curity

I have recently started to use Curity and I am still learning, I have managed to create an authenticator that requires access to a secret in Azure.

```
        ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId("").tenantId("").clientSecret("").build();

        TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId("").tenantId("").clientSecret("").build();
```

When I then try to fetch the actual secret I get the following messages.

```
 io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:478) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$1.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:425) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.handshakeException(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1860) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.wrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:815) ~[?:?]
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:514) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:1059) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:944) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1421) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1265) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1302) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447) ~[?:?]
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslEngine cannot be cast to org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine
        at org.openjsse.sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:273) ~[openjsse.jar:1.1.5]
        at org.openjsse.sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:147) ~[openjsse.jar:1.1.5]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:234) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:717) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:634) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1258) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1384) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1427) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:208) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1358) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1265) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1302) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447) ~[?:?]
        ... 17 more
        Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.sslReadErrorResult(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1347) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1308) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1384) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1427) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:208) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1358) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1265) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1302) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$1.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:425) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[?:?]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[?:?]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
```

I have tried to add all Certificate authorities by Azure into Curity's server truststore without any success. Any ideas on how I can make any progress from here?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/certificate-authorities
https://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/Docs/Repository.htm
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/tls-certificate-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in the JSSE provider. https://github.com/openjsse/openjsse/issues/22

The upcoming 6.3 version upgrades the JRE to a version that includes this fix.